# Why does my simple AngularJS view template show up but browser has syntax error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS (below is the start of my first app), so please bear with me.

The app seems to work, as the select control displays.

But when I run the app in the browser, I get this error in the console:
SyntaxError: syntax error

If I replace the programList.html HTML with this the error does not occur and the code itself displays:

```
var test = 'OK';
```

I'm sure I'm making a basic mistake, but please help me out.

```
--------------------- index.html ---------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myPublicRadioApp">
<body data-ng-cloak data-ng-controller="appController">
    <section class="content" data-ng-view></section>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/myPublicRadioApp/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/myPublicRadioApp/views/programList.html"></script>
    <script src="app/myPublicRadioApp/controllers/programListController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

--------------------- app.js ---------------------
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myPublicRadioApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        var viewBase = 'app/myPublicRadioApp/views/';

        $routeProvider
            .when('/programList', {
                controller: 'ProgramListController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'programList.html',
                controllerAs: 'plc'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/programList' });
    }]);

    app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $document) {
        $scope.appTitle = 'My Public Radio';
        $scope.appSubTitle = 'Making it easier to enjoy public radio online.';
        $document[ 0 ].title = $scope.appTitle;
    });
}());

--------------- programListController.js -----------------
(function() {
    var injectParams = ['$http'];

    var ProgramListController = function ($http) {
        var plc = this;
    };

    ProgramListController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('myPublicRadioApp').controller('ProgramListController', ProgramListController);
}());

---------------- programList.html ---------------
<div>
    <header>
        <label>
            Choose program:
            <select>
                <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `<script src="app/myPublicRadioApp/views/programList.html"></script>`, it is not a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need this line:

```
<script src="app/myPublicRadioApp/views/programList.html"></script>
```

Angular will handle loading this HTML partial because you have specified it here: `templateUrl: viewBase + 'programList.html',`.

The error is thrown because the browser is loading an HTML file as a script and interpreting it as JavaScript, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. AngularJS rocks!